# Python Mount CIFS share with space in linux

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to mount to a CIFS share with space in my linux machine using python like below:

```
from subprocess import call
t = mount -t cifs -o username=kalair2 "//10.32.135.87/root/Singapore Lab/SYMM"      /mnt/share
print t
if os.path.exists("/mnt/share"):
    print "/mnt/share path already exists"
else:
    call("mkdir /mnt/share")
    call("chmod 777 /mnt/share")
    print "mnt/share has been created"
call(t)
```

> But ended up in the error... Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "mounttest.py", line 12, in 
>       call(t)   File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 478, in call
>       p = Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs)   File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 642, in **init**
>       errread, errwrite)   File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1234, in _execute_child
>       raise child_exception OS Error: [Err no 2] No such file or directory

It works if i execute this mount command in shell with space. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping your space:

```
"//10.32.135.87/root/Singapore\ Lab/SYMM"
```

Answer (score 0):

`call` should be called with an array of arguments - not a single string for the command with the arguments, as documented here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Your command should look like this:

`call(["mkdir", "/mnt/share"])`